# Facebook ios sdk 3.10 openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions doesn't callback using web login

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I already have setup the FacebookAppID, FacebookDisplayName, URLSchemes in info.plist file. And in my original viewController, i have the following function.

But, after calling openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions, it's not called NSLog and so on.

```
- (IBAction)facebookLoginButtonClickHandler:(id)sender
{

    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"email", @"read_stream", @"user_about_me", @"user_birthday",
                            nil];
    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:true completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"session = %@", session);
        NSLog(@"error = %@", error);

        if (status == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed || status == FBSessionStateCreatedOpening) {
            [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
        } else if (!session.isOpen) {
            [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"accessToken = %@", session);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add this to your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBAppEvents activateApp];
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```